# FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP without killing activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, back-stack

I am currently trying to figure out a way to achieve the following desired behaviour

**All activities start in the current task, but can only have one instance. If there are other instances, the old one is killed and the new one is started just like a normal activity in default mode**

Consider `A->B->C->D`, where `D` is the top.

1) `A->B->C->D`, Activity `D` starts new activity of type `B`, `A->C->D->B`

2) `A->X->C->D`, Activity `D` starts new activity of type `B`, `A->X->C->D->B`

3) `A->X->C->D->B`, Activity `D` starts new activity of type `B`, `A->X->C->D->B`

In scenario 3, if `B` already exists at the top of the back stack when `D` creates a new `B`, then the old `B` should be killed before a new `B` spawned in its place (or alternative we could just leave it alone, either way really)

How do I go about implementing this? What flags do i need to set on my `INTENT` OR `MANIFEST` to achieve this?

Comment: It is actually a stack, not a list. You can't delete items from the middle of the stack without affecting all elements on top of it.

Comment: Scenario #3 hopefully does not exist, as D has no business starting an activity when it is not the top-most on the stack.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Then explain why I can do `startActivity(); finish();` Technically this is deleting from the middle of the list, yes?

Comment: @Alan - well, both `startActivity()` and `finish()` are asynchronous (your Activity does not immediately start right when you call `startActivity`, nor does `onDestroy()` get called right when you call `finish()`), so the order of the two methods don't matter, so that's equivalent to removing the top activity and then adding a new activity